# Find the location of a character in the alphabet and encrypt it

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I want to ask the user for a string and associate each of its letters to its numeric position in the alphabet to return like this:

```
EGG = 577
```

Here is my code:

```
print "Quelle est votre nom?"
user_Name = gets.chomp
name = user_Name.split(%r{\s*})
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet_Count = alphabet.split("")
name.each_char { |chr|  } do
  until { |chr| == alphabet_Count[i]}
      puts alphabet_Count[i]
  end
end
```

I get an error when I run the code:

```
alphabet.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting end-of-input
name.each_char { |chr|  } do
                          ^~
```

Comment: "1234" could also be "LCD" (12, 3, 4) or "AWD" (1, 23, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the char index on the alphabet, you could use array [index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/index) method, like this:

```
alphabet_Count = ("a".."z").to_a
alphabet_Count.index(anychar.downcase)
```

Note that if you use `index` method, letter `'a'` would be indexed as `0`, so you would have to add an offset of value `1`. Also, there is indeed a syntax error on your loop. Try this:

```
name.each_char do |chr|
  puts alphabet_Count.index(chr.downcase)
end
```

or this:

```
name.split('').each do |chr|
    puts alphabet_Count.index(chr.downcase)
end
```

In ruby, if you iterate using something like:

```
list.each do
    any_code_block
end
```

This means that `any_code_block` would be executed once for each element in `name`. Since in your case you would need to use the `element` on each iteration, you need to specify a variable name to receive `element` value. You do that using `|variable_receiving_element_value|`.

Comment: Thank you, but i still get an error when i run the code 

`alphabet.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
name.each_char |chr| do
                     ^~
alphabet.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
`

Comment: @AlexZi I'm sorry I wasn't with Ruby on my machine at the time. I've updated my answer and tested the code on an online interpreter, it's ok now

Comment: I'm much more familiar with `smt_iterable.each do |value| code_block end` than using brackets syntax. I think using `each do |value|` is more meaningful, easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you, while trying both methods i've managed to get it running while removing the `(anychar.upcase)` but i'm not sure of the result seem to be some hexadecimal values but doesnt seem to be right i'll be working on this myself i just needed to understand how to loop with ruby and you've been really helpfull with that! 1000 thanks :)

Comment: @AlexZi yes I did a ton of edits on the code after testing on the online interpreter. In your code it'd be nice to add `.downcase` instead, so your code would be case insensitive. I guess I might have added a few unwanted topics on my answer indeed haha. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: `alphabet_Count = ("a".."z").to_a`

Comment: @steenslag thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer using range instead of whole alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you is incorrect

You should follow either do...end or {}. Only one is enough

Here is the code without syntax error

```
print "Quelle est votre nom?"
user_Name = gets.chomp
name = user_Name.split(%r{\s*})
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet_Count = alphabet.split("")
name.each_char do |chr|
  until (chr == alphabet_Count[i])
      puts alphabet_Count[i]
  end
end
```